# calculate size of faces to have similar volume of platonic solids

Tags: solid-geometry, platonic-solids

I need to build some prototype physical shapes of the 5 [platonic solids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid).

But the problem is that I want to make them all about the same size,

so how to calculate how big should the faces of my solids have to be in order to have all 5 shapes with an approximate similar volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linked site](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/platonic-solids.html) expresses the areas and volumes in terms of edge-length. Should work for you...